# Disable Trigger To Insert From Backup

Tags: sql, database, oracle

If I'm importing data into a table, and I know the data will not violate table integrity (i.e. importing from a backup table), is it safe to disable the triggers on the table to make importing easier?

Comment: Sure, if you don't need any of the operations the triggers perform. And if no other users will insert data in the meantime, because disabling triggers will affect all sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortly: it depends on what your triggers do.

If your triggers are just implementing some kind of integrity check (or they are performing some read-only operations), then, as long as your backup is valid, it should be safe to disable them. It really depends on the definitions of those integrity constraints.

If your trigges are performing some write operations, you should ask to your self if it's safe to let the triggers enabled. There are two cases:

1. The operations performed are *idempotent*: it's ok both to let triggers enabled and to disable them. Disabling them would lead to gain in performance.
2. The operations performed are *not idempotent*: you have to disable them, or they will break integrity.